# Java: Can't get "nice" random index numbers

Tags: java, random

Update: the problem is with usage, not so much the method being used. I tried to delete the question but I can't do it now, as there are answers...

I need a method that accepts an ArrayList of strings and uses that as a "source" from which to generate a new, randomly assembled, ArrayList of a specified length. 
Actually, I need a few of those random ArrayLists results in each run!

My first approach:

```
public static ArrayList<String> mixFromInput (ArrayList<String> input, int outputLength) {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0; i<outputLength; i++) {
        result.add(input.get(new Random().nextInt(input.size())));
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, this returns a suspicious "random" result (look at the last several iterations):

```
[Xy13005, Xy13003, Xy13004, Xy13005, Xy13003, Xy13006, Xy13000, Xy13004]
[Xy13004, Xy13004, Xy13004, Xy13003, Xy13006, Xy13006, Xy13005, Xy13004]
[Xy13003, Xy13005, Xy13006, Xy13006, Xy13004, Xy13004, Xy13006, Xy13005]
[Xy13004, Xy13005, Xy13006, Xy13005, Xy13006, Xy13006, Xy13005, Xy13006]
[Xy13005, Xy13005, Xy13006, Xy13006, Xy13005, Xy13006, Xy13004, Xy13006]
[Xy13005, Xy13005, Xy13004, Xy13005, Xy13005, Xy13004, Xy13005, Xy13005]
[Xy13004, Xy13005, Xy13005, Xy13005, Xy13005, Xy13005, Xy13005, Xy13005]
[Xy13005, Xy13004, Xy13004, Xy13005, Xy13005, Xy13005, Xy13005, Xy13005]
[Xy13004, Xy13004, Xy13005, Xy13005, Xy13004, Xy13005, Xy13005, Xy13005]
[Xy13005, Xy13004, Xy13004, Xy13005, Xy13005, Xy13004, Xy13004, Xy13004]
```

(Please ignore that these look like they are numbers. I am not looking to `Xy+randomInt`...)

The input to the above result is: `Xy13000, Xy13001, Xy13002, Xy13003, Xy13004, Xy13005, Xy13006, Xy13007`

I think my problem is that since Random() is using system time, and I am calling it using high performance code, it optimizes after a few iterations and the system time barely moves, yielding much less randomness than I expect - although, I could be wrong?

I thought that by creating a new Random() in each iteration of the result-assembly, it will help with "chaos" but this obviously doesn't work.

Things I tried, and got similar (undesirable) result:

- Moving Random() out of the loop
- `Collections.shuffle(input);` on each iteration
- `Math.random()`

Any ideas how to really shake things up here?

PS: Some code if you want to reproduce yourself:

```
    ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
    test.add("Xy13000");
    test.add("Xy13001");
    test.add("Xy13002");
    test.add("Xy13003");
    test.add("Xy13004");
    test.add("Xy13005");
    test.add("Xy13006");
    test.add("Xy13007");
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        test = mixFromInput(test, unicodeKeyLength);
        System.out.println(test);
    }
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it unfortunately, would you mind post a reproducible example? How do you invoke this method?

Comment: @YassinHajaj sure... Actually, in the reproduction code, it's even higher-performance and I get lots of results that are exactly the same - a repetition of one element of `input`... The first result looks fine and then it does it all within the same system time, apparently

Comment: you shouldn't create a `new Random()` each time. That will initialize based on current clock so if less than a millisecond goes by you likely get the same result

Comment: @GarrGodfrey well, as mentioned, I did try to move ```new Random()``` up :) I guess by calling the function from outside so fast, it doesn't change much because it's only one simple call away and stays about the same... I guess I need to put some "slowing" mechanism inside the static method? I don't want to use a hardcoded sleep interval, for obvious reasons (it's just going to be too accurate again!) :)

Comment: Regarding `new Random().nextInt `, you could simply replace that piece with `ThreadLocalRandom.getCurrent().nextInt `. See [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is actually the way you are calling it.
Move Random() out of the loop, that will help, but the problem is each time you call mixFromInput, you are overwriting your input:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
>>>> changing your input here!
>>>>        test = mixFromInput(test, unicodeKeyLength);
        System.out.println(test);
    }
```

instead, testing like this works well.

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        ArrayList<String> results = mixFromInput(test, unicodeKeyLength);
        System.out.println(results);
    }
```

Comment: oh, of course... I feel so dumb :/ Thanks for taking a look, though! Shall I delete the question?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is sending the output from the first call into the second call. Don't do that.

When you select 8 random values out of 8 values, allowing repeats, it is unlikely that all 8 values will be present in the result. As you can see from the first line of output, the values ending in `1`, `2`, and `7` did not get selected, instead you got 2 of each of the values ending in `3`, `4`, and `5`.

That means that values ending in `1`, `2`, and `7` are forever removed from the value pool, and will never show up, no matter how many iterations you execute.

As you keep executing more and more iterations, the value pool will dwindle, and may end up being just one value, repeated 8 times.

To fix, assign return value to another variable, making `test` effective final.

```java
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    ArrayList<String> result = mixFromInput(test, unicodeKeyLength);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Here is a visual about how this happened

[image]

Comment: oh, of course... I feel so dumb :/ Thanks for taking a look, though! Shall I delete the question?

Comment: Giving Garr the answer. I don't think there is a fair way to pick between you two (maybe randomly? ;) ) but he isn't a StackOverflow mogul like you and he also spent extra time on me in the comments. I hope you understand. Thanks again!

Comment: @DraxDomax Yeah. I doubt anyone else having a similar problem will find this question.

Comment: @Andreas I prepared a little diagram for my answer, but since you already answered I'll add it to yours, feel free to delete it you want

Comment: @YassinHajaj very cool looking, thanks, what did you use to visualize it so nicely?

Comment: I use [draw.io](https://app.diagrams.net/) for nearly everything, really flexible :)